# Grub: can't use arrow keys to navigate (works in Bios)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, keyboard, xubuntu

I have a USB-Keyboard in a non-USB-3 port. I have xubuntu 20.04, Grub 2.04-1ubuntu26 and Windows 10. Boot is on the xubuntu disk. I can't select any boot options. The countdown halts when I press a key, I can press enter to boot into xubuntu, I can use Ctrl-Alt-Del to restart. The keyboard seems to work apart from the arrow keys. I cannot toggle Numlock, light stays on, though. I can use the keyboard just fine in Bios and xubuntu after boot.

This question got asked several times. Solutions that were working for some have not worked out for me:

- switching usb modes in Bios
- changing usb port
- using num-block 2 and 8 to navigate
- navigate with pg down

If it's any use, I got a Logitech G110 keyboard and an ASRock Z68 Pro3 mainboard.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem on a site called superuser with an answer from Lekensteyn as follows:

> On modern Linux distributions using systemd, you can go straight to
> the Firmware setup menu using:
>
> ```
> systemctl reboot --firmware-setup
> ```
>
> Documentation:
> https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#--firmware-setup

I entered the command

```
systemctl reboot --firmware-setup
```

in terminal and the system immediately rebooted to UEFI where I was able to disable ultra fast boot and everything is now as it should be (apart from not having fast boot).

This has worked for me I hope it works for you.

I still don't realise why my keyboard doesn't work with ultra fast boot enabled but at least I now know it doesn't.